# Вывести в табличном формате прогнозные значения ARIMA

Tags: python, predicate

Я новичок в программировании. Пробую построить прогноз при помощи ARIMA.
Параметры удалось подобрать, график получается правдоподобным.
Только я не могу понять, как мне теперь получить сами прогнозные данные ARIMA.
forcast, predict пробовал.
Буду признателен за любую подсказку и помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: forecast - это и есть прогноз

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: используй print(output) полагаю это будет список

Comment: @ganz спасибо за комментарий))  посмотрите, пожалуйста, на картинку. я вывожу график и следом за ним output. Но что это за значения не понимаю? По каким-то данным же график строится, но почему-то вывести эти данные не получается.